# How can an immutable string be implemented in C++?

Tags: c++, string, immutability

All my attempts so far have failed.Basically when I return a copy of the internal char array of the string, that copy has to be released, but I don't know how to release it.Wrapping it in a smart pointer doesn't work out, since it's destructor gets called immediately after I return it.Must I implement something like a garbage collector just for the immutable string?

Comment: Show code which is not working

Comment: How about just using a `const std::string`?

Comment: Why do you think you need to create a copy?

Comment: You can't just wrap some other object's data in a new smart pointer. It's not yours to take ownership of

Comment: If you have a string literal, there's no need to "release" it.

Comment: Keep the data pointer in a `shared_ptr` right from the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const std::string` will be fine.

Comment: Although the performance of copying could be improved in a dedicated immutable string class. Also, `const std::string` cannot be moved from, while a dedicated class could support that. You can similarly play games with substrings, at the risk of keeping some massive buffer hanging around because of a tiny substring that still references it.